# Call server side sub after javascript timer is done

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, vb.net, timer

The countdown timer in the online exam is implemented using JavaScript. If the countdown reaches 0:0:00, it alerts the user and it proceeds to the next web page (shown below):

```
function myTimer(startVal,interval,outputId, dataField){
...
var current = this.value;
    this.OutputCntrl.innerHTML = this.Hours(current) + ':' + this.Minutes(current) + ':' +  this.Seconds(current);
    this.currentTimeOut = setTimeout("Timer.go()", this.interval);
                     }
    else             {
    window.alert("Time is up! Exam will proceed to next module.");
    window.location = "Conf_English.aspx"
                                  }
```

And if there are still some time left, options are shown in the web form (shown below):
[image]

When Proceed Button is click, the questions and answers of the examinee (temporarily stored in a datatable) will be stored in the database.

The problem here is the countdown timer is being run by a client-side script and the insertion of data is coded in the server-side. I can't also make a javascript function that will insert the data because base on what I read on some articles, it is not advisable to access the database through client-side scripts which I see is right base on the concept of ASP.Net. Can someone suggest a good method to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ASP.NET AJAX Page Methods to call a `static` (`Shared` in VB.NET) method on the web server, like this:

Markup:

```
// jQuery DOM ready function
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Wire up click event handler for proceed button
    $('.Proceed').click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "PageName.aspx/SaveToDatabase",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                // Navigate to next page or whatever needs to happen here
            }
        });

        // Stop button from trying to post back to server
        return false;
    });
});

<asp:Button id="ButtonProceed" runat="server" Text="Proceed" CssClass="Proceed" />
```

Note: You can pass data to the ASP.NET AJAX Page Method either through name/value pairs inside of `data: "{}",` or you can build a JavaScript literal and then use `JSON.stringify()` to convert the literal into JSON.

Code-behind:

```
[WebMethod]
public static string SaveToDatabase()
{
    // Save to database logic here
}
```

Comment: I get it now. I've been studying this method for about 2 days now. Thank you. Can I ask another question sir? How will I access the gridview data and put it on the shared method in my vb.net?

Comment: @eirishainjel - it is frowned upon to ask piggy-back questions, please  ask a new question, which shows the changes in code made from this question and then clearly state your intended next goal. Asking more questions in a single question just muddies the water and makes it difficult for anyone else coming to this question later to wade through the multiple questions and finding the information they are looking for.